# CodeIgniter Form Validation with existing $_POST data

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I have a form that I need to validate but I can't figure out how to code the controller so that it works correctly the first time the page is displayed. Here is my code (simplified):

```
function index()

  $data['somedata'] = $this->input->post('somedata');

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('event', 'Event', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric');
  ... more set_rules ...

  if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
  {
    // Hasn't been run or there are validation errors
    $this->load->view('eventview', $data);
  }
  else
  {
    // Process the event
  }
}
```

The problem is that form_validation->run() is never FALSE because the $_POST array contains data from a previous form that is used by this second form. At the very beginning of the form_validation->run() function is the following code:

```
// Do we even have any data to process? Mm?
if (count($_POST) == 0)
{
  return FALSE;
}
```

Since $_POST data exists the count is always greater than zero which results in the validation to be processed on initial page load. 
Any suggestions as to how I might work around this?

Comment: You can use some trigger in current post data that will start form validation, but mind that the next POST request won't contain data from previous form unless you send it behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you save the data from your first form in sessions, then make a redirect to your second form instead of going directly to the next one, with your post data.

This would also be more flexible if you need to reuse any of the submitted data.

Answer (score 0):

In the first form set a hidden input

`<input type="hidden" name="form1" value="form1" />`

Then in your controller check if the field is set, if so store the current post array, and then unset it.

```
if(isset($_POST['form1'])){
  $old_post = $_POST;
  unset($_POST);
}

as I assume you are accessing the $_POST array in your view, instead pass `$old_post` through and use that,
```

e.g. `(isset($old_post) ? $old_post['field_name'] : set_value('field_name))`

Good luck.

Comment: I guess I wasn't sufficiently clear in my description of the problem. The problem is that the $_POST array has existing elements when the controller is invoked. In CodeIgniter's system/libraries/Form_validation.php file, the function run() has a check at the very beginning that checks to see if there are any entries in the $_POST array and if it is empty (count = 0) then it returns false. This is how CodeIgniter determines whether this is the first time through the form. Obviously this is not a very accurate method for doing so and thus my dilemma.